# How to draw an even table border with different border widths?

Tags: css

I implement a crossword generator. It generates a crossword with row-per-word and letter-per-cell, and keyword is marked with wider  border and gray background, like in the image:
[image: Crossword image]

To achieve this, my generated code is roughly the following:

```css
#crossword {
   border-spacing: 0px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}

.word {
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.keyword {
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table id="crossword">
    <tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">W</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">C</td>
        <td class="cell letter">A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is marked by red ellipses in the image - the border of keyword, being 1px wider than the rest, breaks the top and bottom line of the crossword. I tried removing `border-collapse` property, but that caused double borders to appear on each row connection.

Currently I use `table`, `tr` and `td` for generation, but if there is a solution using `div`s, I'll be happy to switch.

So my question is: assuming that I'm able to uniquely address each of the cells (including adding special classes to them etc.), how to make the top and bottom border appear inside the keyword cell, instead of outside?

I found one solution using `box-shadow`, but it's not really cross-browser, and involves a lot of magic, so I'd prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: What about a smaller `border-[top|bottom]-width` for the cells on the edges?

Comment: box-shadow (inset 0 0 0 1px) is fine to thicken border, in obsolete browsers nothing will break. Else you may use 2 different black such as #000 & #333 that will be different enough to be noticed :) (life is filled of compromise) also lazy to turn this into an answer and a snippet cause you did not let us any html to play with ;)

Comment: @casraf this of course causes the line to be even, but is also a noticable change in width pattern, which I'd prefer to avoid

Comment: But what's the desired behavior? If you want to border to be thicker, that's what you get.

Comment: @Oriol - the desired behavior is to get border thicker, but at the same time leave the top and bottom lines even - this means that the additional pixels in the border should be drawn _inside_ the `td` element, not outside. I'd also want it to run cross-browser, at least in FF and Chrome

Comment: @TomaszLewowski Ah, if you want the border to grow inwards you can use a box-shadow like GCyrillus says, or maybe insert a pseudo-element.

Comment: @Oriol - the approach with pseudo-element works of course - if there is no better solution I'll pick it (I already implemented it, so I'm sure it works). Shadow seems kinda hairy, as it's support varies significantly between browsers. Interestingly, `box-sizing:border-box` is sufficient for FF, but not in Chrome.

Comment: OK, I see the problem now, browser compat is a mess. Pseudo-elements don't work on Firefox because with `border-collapse: collapse` they can't be positioned correctly. Hopefully the new CSS Tables Level 3 module will make browsers unify their behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep outermost border of the table to match the table's default border by using

```
table#crossword tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table#crossword tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
table#crossword tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
table#crossword tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

It looks a bit low, but you have no other option to other than this to make outermost border evenly aligned

**Demo**

```css
#crossword {
   border-spacing: 0px;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}

.word {
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.keyword {
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
}

table#crossword tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table#crossword tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
table#crossword tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="crossword">
    <tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">W</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">C</td>
        <td class="cell letter">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">W</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">C</td>
        <td class="cell letter">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">W</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">C</td>
        <td class="cell letter">A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, I was able to achieve what I'm looking for by inserting another `div` into the keyword `td` and styling the `div` to have a border in top/bottom (just a few minutes ago). It works, so I definitely wouldn't say there is no option to do this - now I'm simply looking for a better one. If no better solution comes up, I'll post it here for the next generations

Answer (score 1):

If you add 'box-sizing: border-box;' only for the `.keyword` class , it works - at least it doesn't go out of the outer border of the table:

```css
#crossword {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#crossword .keyword {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.word {
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.letter {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.keyword {
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table id="crossword">
    <tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">W</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">C</td>
        <td class="cell letter">A</td>
    </tr>
<tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">B</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">K</td>
        <td class="cell letter">L</td>
    </tr>
<tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">F</td>
        <td class="cell letter keyword">R</td>
        <td class="cell letter">V</td>
    </tr>  
  <tr class="word">
        <td class="cell letter">T</td>
        <td class="cell letter">E</td>
        <td class="cell letter">Q</td>
    </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not cross-browser - it works in Firefox and Edge, but not in Chrome (not sure about Opera and Safari, I didn't check)